# Can a delegate in C# contain a collection of objects?

Tags: c#, delegates, observer-pattern

Assume the following Observer Pattern as described in the UML diagram below:
[image]

Previously, the subscribers to the publisher were updated by the `Notify()` method in `Academy` through a collection `List<Student> students` called when setting `Academy.Message` probing their `Update()` function.

This can apparently, according to the assignment, be done by a delegate too. How is this possible? How can objects be added to something that is not a collection?

The following code is supposed to call `Update()` when `p.Message` is set:

```
 var p = new Academy("College", "3rd Street");
 var s1 = new Student(p, "Joe");
 var s2 = new Student(p, "John");
 var s3 = new Student(p, "Susan");
 p.Attach(s1);
 p.Attach(s2);
 p.Attach(s3);
 p.Message = "Module A has been cancelled!";
 p.Detach(s2);
 p.Message = "Module B has been cancelled!";
```

Comment: See: [Multicast Delegates in C#](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/multicast-delegate-csharp/).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I know about delegate multicasting but how are the students stored in the delegate if there isn't a collection?

Comment: @Aleksandar a delegate is the collection. (it's a collection containing a MethodInfo and the owner instance which has that method. When the delegate is "fired" it triggers all the methods in the delegate. That's why there is a collection of students, because the instances are stored.

Comment: The questions is: what does `Academy.Attach` do? The Academy could actually hold a collection of students to be notified or add the `Student.Update` method to a multicast delegate. `Attach(student)` does not necessarily mean that the student is added.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I see - but shouldn't the delegate then also have the same parameter from the DCD being `IObserver o`? The `Update()` in `Student` is supposed to print a statement for each separate instance when being called by `Notify()`. I think I am closer to understanding it, but not quite yet. You basically store each object as an invocation instead of doing it in a list.

Comment: Don't quite get what you are asking. A delegate is a list of references to methods. It only knows about those method nothing about the instance/classes this method belongs to(the internals are a bit different but just assume whats surfaced and needs to be known to be used). So Attach might add a reference to the IObserver.Update method to the delegate but that delegate doesn't know it was from IObserver/Student it will just be happy because the expected signature fits. Its not comparable to your List<Student> its more like a List<MethodInfo>.

Comment: @Ralf It's from an old assignment - I will have to ask the professor. The assignment is worded such as one should be able to update the methods to fit the new delegate, which doesn't take the object `Student` as an argument and I simply can't fit the methods to it since they need in some way to be passed to be updated

Comment: Students seem to have a reference to Academy which stores the message. So, no parameter is required in Update() for the new message. Students only need to know that the message has changed in order to trigger an appropriate action.

Comment: Note also that there are various ways to implement an observer pattern. A common way in .NET is to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-7.0).